# How does the STM32F446RE Bootloader work?

Tags: stm32, bootloader, stm32f4, usart

I want to connect the STM32F446RE (in the bootloader mode) via USART with my PC to flash some hexfiles on it. 
Between the USB port & the STM (USART1) I got an USB to USART bridge (CP2102).
I used the STM32CubeProgrammer to connect the STM32F446RE with the host.

Everything works really well, but only one thing is a bit tricky.

My problem is, that the connection is not directly established. 
I need about 2 or 3 trys before I can connect with the STM.
After that it works without any further problems.

So my Question is how long does the STM wait for a signal on his RX line.
I found no documentation whatsoever.The AN2606 and AN3155 from ST helped me with other problems but there is no time specified.

So if anyone could help me...

This is the **errorlog**:
    12:01:53 : Response received from device: NACK 12:01:53 : Error: GETID command not acknowledged! 12:01:53 : Reemission of GetID command 12:01:53 : Response received from device: NACK 12:01:53 : Error: GETID command not acknowledged! When I try to connect again it works perfectly. No errors.

USART Connection:  Baudrate 57600
                   Parity: even
                   Data bits: 8
Stop bits:1

Comment: can you elaborate on your 3rd paragraph?

Comment: Yes of course. Let me try to explain it step by step :)   When I try to connect to the STM I get some Errors.                                                                                  12:01:53 : Response received from device: NACK
12:01:53 : Error: GETID command not acknowledged!
12:01:53 : Reemission of GetID command
12:01:53 : Response received from device: NACK
12:01:53 : Error: GETID command not acknowledged!                                                                       When I try to connect again it works perfectly. No errors. Nothing. So I'm a bit confused

Comment: please add your updates to your question by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56645094/edit). (don't forget to format it using the formatting buttons). What software are you using to connect? ST has multiple programs to connect and did you try to connect using a CLI?

Comment: also have you tried a lower baudrate? `9600` and `115200` are some standard ones

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I'll edit the question :) I tried other Baudrates. No suucess. Same error. I used the STM32CubeProgramme. I didn't use a CLI. I'll try and let you know .